# What is the correct way to setup phpdocker with PhpStorm

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm

I am going to setup my Laravel PHP environment using phpdocker (official image). I am sure that my phpdocker can run well with install extension, but when using PhpStorm to interact with phpdocker it can't work well (such as Xdebug can't detect).

I'm using PhpStorm's Deployment feature and SSH connect my PHP Docker container.

Here is my php version:

[image]

```
ARG VERSION="7.3"

FROM php:${VERSION}-cli-alpine

...

# install xdebug
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_XDEBUG} = true ]; then \
      apk add --no-cache $PHPIZE_DEPS \
      && pecl install xdebug-2.7.2 \
      && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
    ;fi

RUN apk add -U --no-cache tzdata \
    && set -xe \
    && apk add --no-cache --update --virtual .phpize-deps $PHPIZE_DEPS \
    && apk add --no-cache libpng-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd bcmath pdo_mysql opcache \
    && apk add --no-cache git composer bash vim
...
```

I expect the PhpStorm to detect Xdebug, but it is not.

PhpStorm setting images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNDtq.jpg

Comment: And how did you configure the server in PHPStorm? It doesn’t “detect” anything by itself. You have to add a remote (docker) server.

Comment: @emix I had configure deployment server. You can see my last image it show phpstorm can detect my php cli with version 7.9, but I dont why it cant detect xdebug.

Comment: When I edit /etc/php7/php.ini, and add xdebug config, it will work well.

Comment: P.S. Do not install `vim` on your production image :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add xdebug config (that's while it works when editing `php.ini`).

Should be something like:

```
RUN echo "zend_extension=$(find /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ -name xdebug.so)" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
```

Or you can `COPY` some prepared `xdebug.ini` file and modify it.

Comment: Yeah, this is one of the way. Actually I expect docker-php-ext-enable/ docker-php-ext-install should do this for me, but it doesn’t...

Comment: @user2986600 yes, that was also confusing for me, but I think this is the best solution.